# AccessDenied SharePoint 2010 WebPart calling external Web Service through full-trust proxy

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I do bother with 'Access Denied' error message while running SharePoint WebPart which in turn trigger external web service call. The web service proxy code is hosted within full-trust proxy.
Now my web parts is SharePoint project scoped at site level and full-trust proxy implemenation lives in another SharePoint project scoped at farm level.

Whole stuff works like a charm while executed on dev machine but crashes in the test environment.
Dev machine is all-in-one SharePoint development environment with domain controller and kerberos.

test environment is ntlm staging environment.

What I am not seeing here? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that it is possible you are logged in while testing in dev with an administrator account.  If your web part calls code that requires a certain level of access, another user may not be able to use it at all.